# Auto Increment Value on SQL SELECT when duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I was wondering if it was possible to do the following. I have a database of first and last names, I'd like to query it so that the results are firstname.lastname or in the case of firstname.lastname already being returned, it should be firstname.lastname1 (or 2 if firstname.lastname1 was already returned, etc). So querying the following table:

```
| ID | Firstname | Lastname |
|  1 |      John |    Smith |
|  2 |      John |    Smith |
|  3 |      Jane |      Doe |
```

would return

```
John.Smith
John.Smith1
Jane.Doe
```

The database exists on MSSQL Server 2008.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    FirstName + '.' + LastName
        + IsNull(cast(NullIf(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName + '.'  + LastName ORDER BY ID) - 1, 0) as varchar(10)), '')
FROM
    TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
SELECT FirstName + '.' + LastName +
    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName ORDER BY ID) As Varchar(9))
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Very close, except I believe this will append a `0` to the end of the first person's name (or anyone who doesn't have duplicates for that matter)

Comment: Thanks! That gets me pretty close, but it still adds the number even if it's not a duplicate. Is there some way to add it only in the case of duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Seq = 1 THEN Firstname + '.' + Lastname 
     ELSE Firstname + '.' + Lastname + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)
END As Name
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Firstname, Lastname,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Firstname, Lastname ORDER BY ID) As Seq
  FROM Sometable
) tbl
```